# Error in source oracle connector stage which is performing just an extract

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, unix, datastage

I am facing below error in a job in the source oracle connector stage which is performing just an extract.

> The OCI function OCIStmtFetch2 returned status -1.
>
> Error code: 1455, Error message: ORA-01455: converting column
> overflows integer datatype. (CC_OraStatement::fetch, file
> CC_OraStatement.cpp, line 1,820)

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type in Oracle?  Typically Oracle specifies NUMBER, which can have as many as 38 digits.  An Integer can have at most 10 digits.
If you import the table definition from Oracle, it will give you a data type for that column with which you can work.  Or - if you must use integer - you can use user-defined SQL to CAST that column AS INTEGER, but you may still hit "too large" problems in this case.